# find elements occurring more than once and delete matlab

Tags: matlab

I have troubles in solving this problem and I ask for your help..

suppose that I have a vector

```
vector1 = [ 1 1 2];
```

with an associated error vector (the first element of `vector1` is linked with the first element of `error1`)

```
error1= [0.08 0.9 0.3];
```

if vector1 contains 2 equal elements (first and second element in this case) I should replace the element with the highest error with NaN

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What if `vector1` contains 3 or 4 or more number of equal elements? Are the values of `error1` always positive values?

Comment: is vector1 sorted? if no, is it a problem if i sort it?

Comment: @Divakar vector1 can contain more than 2 number of equal element. errors are always positive.

Comment: @timgeb vector1 is not sorted. Yes it is a problem for me to sort it.

Comment: @gabboshow So if vector1 contains 3 or 4 number of equal elements, should we replace just the highest error with NaN or every error other than the lowest error?

Comment: @Divakar Hi Divakar, I should replace every element of vector1 that is not associated with the lowest error...

Comment: @gabboshow Check out my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24550209/3293881), if it works for you.

Comment: @gabboshow has any of the solution worked for you? If yes, please accept the answer which suits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
presence_vec_ele = double(bsxfun(@eq,vector1,unique(vector1)'))
presence_vec_ele(presence_vec_ele==0)=nan
[~,min_ind] = nanmin(bsxfun(@times,presence_vec_ele,error1),[],2)
error1(setdiff(1:numel(error1),min_ind))=NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume the following things:

1. `vector1` can have more than 2 equal elements.
2. `error1` can contain negative values.

This may not be the fastest solution, but it works, according to me.

```
% Generating random inputs
vector1=[1 2 2 1 1 1 3 3 4 4 5 5 6];
error=3*randn(1,13);

% Sorting the vector
[vector2,I]=sort(vector1);
error2=error(I);

% finding unique elements and the range of repeated elements is stored in b2
[~,b,~]=unique(vector2)
b2=[b [b(2:end)-1;length(vector2)]]
b2((b2(:,1)-b2(:,2))==0,:)=[]

% Calculating maximum error for those repeated indices.
for i=1:size(b2,1)
   [~,ind]=max(error2(b2(i,1):b2(i,2)));
   maxErrorInd(i,1)=ind+b2(i,1)-1;
end

% Replacing with NaN
vector2(maxErrorInd)=NaN

% Mapping back since we had sorted
vector3(I)=vector2
error3(I)=error2
```